# PyDev external debugging with new python types defined?

Tags: python, c++, c

I have a system where Python is embedded (C++ System) and that embedded python is further extended with the C++ application itself.

My problems started when I decided to include a new type definition in the Python extension. I get to define a new type using -> https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html . But then the application crash (both in C++ and Python [Fatal Python error: UNREF invalid object]).

If I deactivate the lines that connect the python interpreter to the external PyDev debugger everything works just fine but if I activate those the crash appears.

Do you have any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, apparently this is an issue in your C/C++ code. I believe that the debugger is just exposing an existing bug in your code (i.e.: the debugger will inspect your objects doing a dir() on them and possibly calling repr() or str() -- and **probably** during this process your object is doing something bad).

My suggestion is compiling your code in debug mode (and generating an _d library) and then running with python in debug (native) mode with python_d.

I.e.: configure python_d inside Eclipse/PyDev, launching your code with python_d and attaching your C/C++ debugger to the running process.

Note that if it's too difficult to have python_d and all dependencies you need in debug mode, there may be some workarounds on to generate a release library with debug information (but the ideal is actually having python and all dlls in debug mode).